# Ionic 3 native google maps restrict map move/drag/rotate options

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am developing a tablet application using ionic native google maps. I didn't find options on the document to restrict map move/drag and map rotate. Basically I want to set these options disabled. Users should not move the map beyond the boundaries and should not rotate the map direction.

Somebody please let me know how to disable these features on ionic native google maps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solutions for it.

```
let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
  gestures:{
    rotate:false,
    tilt:false,
    scroll:false
  }
};

this.map = this.googleMaps.create(this.mapDiv.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```